# Rails 3 noob - getting value from application_controller to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I understand that the application_controller will produce variable values for an entire application but have never applied that knowledge. There is a variable that comes up in most of my controllers... @qs for the number of questions. The following code is not working.

application_controller:

```
  def qs
    if current_user.sec_paid and current_user.min_paid
      @qs = 36
    elsif current_user.sec_paid
      @qs = 25
    else
      @qs = 5
    end
  end
```

applets_controller:

```
@strengths = Strength.where("position <= ?", @qs).order("position")
```

applet1.html.erb:

```
<%=@qs.to_i%>
```

The output to a view file is just a way to test for the value of the variable and will be removed. Currently it produces a zero.

Any help is appreciated. Specific changes to my code is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`before_filter :qs`](http://www.fortytwo.gr/blog/6/Rails-Power-to-the-filters) in your ApplicationControler (or in those controllers it is needed) to invoke the `qs` method on every call. In this way the `@qs` variable will be initialized.